# how to call selectItemAtIndexPath immediately

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview

I am using this line

```
[self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
```

inside the cellForItemAtIndexPath method, to programatically select an item in the collection view and it is working, the problem is that it only works after I touch the collection view. How do I get it to work immediately after the collection view is loaded?

Comment: Call it in viewDidAppear.

Comment: But I need the index of the item I want to select

Answer (score 0):

Call it inside viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

If you know the position you want to select on load, you can create a NSIndexPath object by using: `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]`

For example: `NSIndexPath *myIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];`

Comment: Hi, I know the indexPath I want to select inside the cellForItemAtIndexPath by doing some validations, this is why I put it inside this method

Comment: The cellForRowAtItemIndex method calls once per collection item on view load. So if you put something there, you should see the last item on UIcollectionView selected on load.